# Instantly update my activity when SMS receiving

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to update the SMS counter in my main activity as I am receiving new SMS at real time.
how could I do this?

Code Here:

```
public class SMSBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // code...
     }
   }
```

in this way I can not update my main activity's counter without restarting.

thanks,

Comment: Ok, let me say it simple way. I have MainActivity which has text view counting some specific number's sms, when my MainActivity alive, it is updated automatically received sms.

Answer (score 2):

Application will need to make communication between SMS `BroadcastReceiver` and Activity when any new SMS received.For informing Activity  new SMS,you can use BroadcastReceiver with custom action.

**STEP 1:** Add custom Action in Activity:

```
public static String SMSRECEVID="custom.action.SMSRECEVEDINFO";
```

**STEP 2:** Create BroadcastReceiver for updating Activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver smsReceived=new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Your_Activity_Name.SMSRECEVID)){
                   // update UI of Activity
         }
    }
};
```

**STEP 3:** From `SMSBroadcast` class send broadcast when sms received :

```
public class SMSBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction(Your_Activity_Name.SMSRECEVID);
          context.sendBroadcast(intent);
     }
   }
```

if `SMSBroadcast` in separate class is not requirement for your project then no need to use above steps just use SMSBroadcast as `anonymous inner type` in Activity in which you want to update UI elements when new SMS received. also don't forget to unregister BroadcastReceiver on Activity Stop or destroy

Comment: work by changing SMSRECEVID="custom.action.SMSRECEVEDINFO" to SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" In my broadcastreceiver class I intercept it from default SMS using receiver.abortBroadCast() intent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);    intent.setAction(MainActivity.SMSRECEVID);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
abortBroadcast(); in this case I could not get any INFO in my MyActivity BroadcastReceiver receiver_SMS=new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
btn_sms.setText("OK");
}
}
};

Comment: @RealDream: if you are using `SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` means registering BroadcastReceiver as `anonymous inner type` in Activity so no need use custom BroadcastReceiver as i was already mentioned in my answer

Comment: So what is that representing "custom.action.SMSRECEVEDINFO"?

Comment: @RealDream : I my answer i have mention two points. FIRST : if your are using SMS broadcast reviver from AndroidManifast and separate class then to inform activity when new sms received use custom BroadcastReceiver with any unique action like in my answer i am using `"custom.action.SMSRECEVEDINFO"` SECOND: if it's not project requirement to create separate listener class and register through AndroidManifast then just register BroadcastReceiver for `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` by creating BroadcastReceiver as anonymous inner type in Activity same i am doing in step 2

Answer (score 0):

may be this one help you...

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    IncomingMessageReceiver.dbServices = new DatabaseServices(context);
    contact = new SaveNewContact(context);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (Object obj : objects) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                        .createFromPdu((byte[]) obj);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                        .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                if (contact.getCallerName(phoneNumber) != null)
                    phoneNumber = contact.getCallerName(phoneNumber);
                String msg_content = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                // further logic of your application
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

and this in manifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name="[your receiver]" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```